# Google MK-map view and Mk-map type via segmented control selection

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Here is the code

```
-(id) initWithNibName:(NSString*) nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil
{
   ...
   [segCtrl addTarget:self action:@selector(OnSegCtrlChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(void)OnSegCtrlChanged:(id)sender
{
   if(segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
   {
      [mapvw setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
   }
   else if//....
}
```

My code to change the map image display looks just like that and sadly, nothing works at all after I compile and run the program. "Nothing works" means no corresponding maptype is displayed after I select an index from the segmented control on the screen.

[**UPDATE**] I would guess the initialization of the segmented control as I put in the InitWIthNibName is not correct as it is not the right place to start. If not, where should I leave it though ?

Comment: Is `OnSegCtrlChanged` called ??? use breakpoint

Comment: try initializing the segmented control in viewDidLoad: instead of initWithNibName:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set target in `viewDidLoad:` method.. like bellow..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
       .....
      [segCtrl addTarget:self action:@selector(OnSegCtrlChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set it in `loadView` method..

```
- (void)loadView
{
       .....
      [segCtrl addTarget:self action:@selector(OnSegCtrlChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

this might be better....